# PDF editing web-application with drag and drop

Tags: web-applications, drag-and-drop, image-editing

I want to create some webapp for editing image with drag and drop (remove logo, and put an other one, editing the text in the image etc).
I explain, I create communication poster, but some people don't really like, the slogan on the poster, or they want to add their logo on the poster, add their website etc. That's what I want to create for user, be able to modify this kind of things on a PDF editor online, re-save at PDF and download it, directly on my website. 
I don't know if something like that exist already.
Have you some way to explore ?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of online tools that let you edit images..

Here's a relatively simple one that I found while Googling: https://www.picozu.com/editor/

If that one doesn't fit your needs try searches like "online graphics editing program", "online image editor", or "online drawing editor"

Comment: Sorry, by image I mean PDF image

Comment: @NathanMeyer then edit it in your main post

Comment: PDFs aren't necessarily images, you should update your question to reflect what you need. Unfortunately when PDFs are involved, things can get a bit more complicated due to the fact that a PDF can be composed in a number of ways. Your image may be part of a larger watermark, or if you're lucky, a separate entity.

Comment: I have editing the question to be more clear